# Pass a user-specific variable to every jade page from node

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have a nav bar view in my node app which puts the bar across the top of the screen on every page in the site. I would like to allow the user to access their profile from this nav bar, and display the username.

I am aware that I can use app.locals to get a variable from any page, but I want this to be different for different users. Do I need to just pass the username and profile link manually in every route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`res.locals`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.locals), which is scoped to the current request (as opposed to `app.locals` which is scoped to the entire app).